# where do i need to create a subfolder named “tessdata” inside my sdcard?

Tags: android

i have copy pasted a program of tesseract tess-two OCR inside my program and i am getting this error " Data path must contain subfolder tessdata ". I want to know exactly where am i supposed to create this subfolder and how to specify the path in my program , i have followed most of the links which had solutions but not working for me , may be i am following it in a wrong way . I am posting my code here , please suggest me the changes that i have to make. My sdcards location for the images is /storage/sdcard0/... , i am retrieving it with the the help of MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA and my images are getting displayed properly , so suggest me according to my code , it would be of a great help to me.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
        && null != data) {

    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
         };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

   // File tessdata = new File(picturePath);
    //if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory()) {
     //   throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      //          "Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");
    //}

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    int newWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int newHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    while (newWidth > 1200) {
        newWidth = newWidth / 2;
        newHeight = newHeight / 2;
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
            newWidth, newHeight, false));

    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    int rotate = 0;

    switch (exifOrientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
    }

    if (rotate != 0) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        // Setting pre rotate
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(rotate);

        // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
    }
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();

    baseApi.init(picturePath, "eng");

    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    baseApi.end();

}
```

i have created a folder named tesseract_languages and inside i have created a subfolder tessdata , is it wrong ? if it is ? then where do i have to create the subfolder ?, if it is right then how to specify it in my program , please guide me Thanking You.

Comment: `and i am getting this error`. On which code line?. `i have created a folder named tesseract_languages`. Where exactly?

Comment: i created the folder tesseract_languages and inside that a subfolder named tessdata and inside that i have eng.traineddata, inside my sdcard

Comment: Please tell full path.

Comment: /storage/sdcard0/tesseract_languages/tessdata/eng.traineddata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File tessdata = new File(picturePath);
if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");
}
```

This is nonsense code as picturePath is a path to a picture just selected from the Gallery or something like that. So it probably will exist. It will not be a directory as it is a file. And further there is no check if the parh contains a directory with the name tessdata. Finally this is your own error message where you explained it to us as coming from the ocr module.

Further you will have the mentioned error on code line

```
baseApi.init(picturePath, "eng");
```

You should not use a path to a picture there but the path to your language files.

```
baseApi.init(languageFilesPath, "eng");
```

As the path of the language file is

```
/storage/sdcard0/tesseract_languages/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

You should use for languageFilesPath

```
/storage/sdcard0/tesseract_languages
```

Comment: sir if i remove the above check then also it shows the same error

Comment: When? On which line you forgot to tell. And please answer my other questions.

Comment: the error message is coming from TessBaseApi.class 
 public boolean init(String datapath, String language) {
        if (datapath == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must not be null!");
        if (!datapath.endsWith(File.separator))
            datapath += File.separator;

        File tessdata = new File(datapath + "tessdata");
        if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");

        return nativeInit(datapath, language);
    }

Comment: Ok. So now you know exactly what `languageFilesPath` should be!? Show here please what you use.

Comment: sir i wanted to ask do i need to specify the full path of my languages file after picturePath ??

Comment: What you have to do is exactly mentioned in my updated answer.

Comment: yea sir my bad , when i debugged it , i found out the picture path was my pictures path and not the languages path , sorry ,and thank you for finding out the mistake , +1 upvote for your patience and answer